# Datagrid binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I know this has been asked already but I have done almost everything what is suggested by developers.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Imported" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          DataContext="{Binding Source=list}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Date}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I am trying to show this in modal dialog box and populating the license list in the constructor of the modal dialog box.
But still nothing is getting populated inside the `DataGrid`.

Constructor code:

```
public diagboxclass()
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list = GetObjectList();
}
public class object
{
    string id;
    DateTime date;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }
}
```

Do you guys think something to do with the object list?

Comment: My list object has more other properties than the two above which im not binding? would that can make any diff?

Comment: Probably not. Please share some more of your XAML (including how `list` is defined) so we can help further.

Comment: I have added code on the top.

Comment: @alice7 What type is the `diagboxclass`? What type is the XAML class `containing` the DataGrid? If `diagboxclass` is in the code-behind of the XAML file, you should assign `list` to the `DataContext` property of that class. You should then be able to bind to list from within the XAML.

Comment: @djacobson: I got it resolved. Looks like xaml was tryin to load the list when the modal dialog was getting called and as the list was empty when the xaml was getting loaded. So what I did is not setting itemresources in xaml and tried on back hand inside constructor and that did the magic.

Comment: I added this inside the constructor: Imported.ItemsSource = list;

Comment: Hi, If one of the Answers helped you back in 2011 please mark it as Answer, thx

Answer (score 46):

PLEASE do not use **object** as a class name:

```
public class MyObject //better to choose an appropriate name
{
    string id;
    DateTime date;
    public string ID
    {
       get { return id; }
       set { id = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
       get { return date; }
       set { date = value; }
    }
}
```

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this class and of course **call it on the Property setter**. Otherwise changes are not reflected in your ui.

Your **Viewmodel class/ dialogbox class should have a** `Property` of your `MyObject` list. `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` is the way to go:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList
{
     get...
     set...
}
```

In your `xaml` you should set the `Itemssource` to your collection of `MyObject`. (the `Datacontext` have to be your dialogbox class!)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=MyList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>                
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: In my case the ItemSource of the DataGrid should be:  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"

Answer (score 24):

Without seeing said object list, I believe you should be binding to the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property, not its `DataContext`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Imported" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source=list}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

(This assumes that the element [`UserControl`, etc.] that contains the `DataGrid` has **its** `DataContext` bound to an object that contains the `list` collection. The `DataGrid` is derived from `ItemsControl`, which relies on its `ItemsSource` property to define the collection it binds its rows to. Hence, if `list` isn't a property of an object bound to your control's `DataContext`, you might need to set both `DataContext={Binding list}` and `ItemsSource={Binding list}` on the `DataGrid`).

Comment: @alice7 Then please post some XAML showing the rest of your Window/UserControl/Whatever contains the grid, and let us know how `list` is defined. :)

Comment: I have removed the entire content and just left the datagrid.so there is no other control. Here is the code isnide constructor: List<object> objectList = new List<object>();  objectList = GetObjectList();

Comment: Inside the constructor of... what? Please edit your question (click the `edit` link that appears beneath the tags) to include further code; it's pretty difficult to read in a comment. Thanks :)

Comment: @alice7: You need to expose that list as a public property and set an appropriate DataContext, you should probably read [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: @djacobson: This one is yours.

Comment: I have added all the code to the top that is there. And I know that list of objects is not null.

Comment: The Binding in the ItemsSource Property is maybe wrong. In my case I was not successful when I declare the Binding with "{Binding Source=list}". But I was successful when I declare the Binding with "{Binding list}".

Answer (score 5):

Try to do this in the behind code:

```
public diagboxclass()
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list = GetObjectList();
    Imported.ItemsSource = null;
    Imported.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Also be sure your list is effectively populated and as mentioned by @Blindmeis, never use words that already are given a function in C#.