# Double binding on a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am new to mvvm and I am not really familiar with the control DataGrid. I would like to known if we can do multiple binding on a DataGrid or anything.

Let me explain, I have 3 TextBox ( ProductName, Quantity, Price ) and i have 4 colums in my dataGrid ( ProductName, Quantity, Price, Total(price*quantity)). I also have 2 bouton, (add product) which will add the textBox value to the DataGrid and a bouton (save) which will save the content of the dataGrid in a DataBase.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Post the relevant code and XAML and please be specific about what issues / errors you're facing.

Comment: You may be interested in reading an article I wrote for WPF beginners: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). It will hopefully give you a better idea about how WPF works, and of what you need to build to get what you want. You may also want to check out [a simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)  :)

Comment: The answer is 'yes, you can do that'.  If such were not possible, wpf wouldn't be much use would it?  Start with a tutorial and you'll see how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataSource of the DataGrid should point to a collection of items.

Each row will be a single entity of your collection and it's properties can then be bound to a column (using templates).

See:
[Datagrid binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf)