# How can i bind an ID to a datagrid.selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I bind these two properties? I tried SelectedValue and I get

> System.NullReferenceException

I tried to add it with SelectedIndex, but it doesn't bind the right one.

I tried SelectedItem but I get

> System.InvalidCastException

also tried with binding in xaml : `SelectedValuePath="ClientId"`

My Question what do I use to bind these properties?

```
Reservation rs = new Reservation();
{
      rs.ClientId = (int)ClientDataGrid.SelectedValue;
      rs.RoomId = (int)AvailableRoomDataGrid.SelectedValue;
}

in class Reservation :

public int? ClientId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ClientId")]
public Client Client { get; set; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty sample.
On load, I initialize the grid and add a couple records to it. Then when button is clicked, the selected FName populates the `TheName` variable.

I'm guessing this(tailored to YOUR class) would take care of your invalid cast on SelectedItem.
`((FamilyMember)dg_MainGrid.SelectedItem).FName`

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg_MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-14.748,-2.867"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,291,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        BindingList<FamilyMember> Family = new BindingList<FamilyMember>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDG();
            AddFamilyMembers();
        }

        private void InitializeDG()
        {
            dg_MainGrid.ItemsSource = Family;
            dg_MainGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }

        private void AddFamilyMembers()
        {
            Family.Add(new FamilyMember { FName = "Name1", LName = "D", Notes = "34" });
            Family.Add(new FamilyMember { FName = "Name2", LName = "L", Notes = "36" });
            Family.Add(new FamilyMember { FName = "Name3", LName = "D", Notes = "7" });
            Family.Add(new FamilyMember { FName = "Name3", LName = "D", Notes = "5" });
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string TheName = ((FamilyMember)dg_MainGrid.SelectedItem).FName;//get the selected FName
        }
    }

    public class FamilyMember
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```