# Error while doing a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm having a problem when I want to make a table using a `DataTable` and a `DataGrid`, simply by saying the Rows' lines it appears a following error:

> DataGrid does not contain a definition for' Rows' and could not find any 'Rows' extension method that accepts a first argument of type' DataGrid '(is there a usage directive or missing assembly reference?)

I really do not know what to do, read the code I used below, the part of the error I left in bold.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_salvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable Tabela = new DataTable();

        Tabela.Columns.Add("Name");
        Tabela.Columns.Add("Region:");

        DataRow row = Tabela.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = "";
        row["Region"] = "";
        Tabela.Rows.Add(row);

        foreach (DataRow drow in Tabela.Rows) ;
        {
            int Livros = Tabela_.**ROWS**.Add();
            Tabela_Livro.**ROWS**[num].Cells[0]Value = drow["Name"].ToString();
            Tabela_Livro.**ROWS**[num].Cells[1]Value = drow["Region"].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the for..each?  Your table only has the one row you added.

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the foreach line that will cause trouble.

Comment: What the hell is this - `Tabela_.**ROWS**.Add();`???

Comment: If have data table, no need for `for-loop`. Just assign datasource

Comment: If you have a DataGridView then all you need to do to add DataTable is : datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I put this to make the error highlighted, I am new to the site. @jdweng I wanted to do it in a way that did not need servers (sql) so I chose the DataTable.

Comment: You are not correct.  Using DataSource in this case has nothing to do with a server.  A DataTable is an object in the System.Data library that is part of your application with no connections to a server.

Comment: @jdweng how or where could I be implementing it in my code? because I tried to put it in the same place as the last and gave the same problem, only instead of 'Rows gave' DataSource '

Comment: Remove the for loop and replace with : Tabela_Livro.DataSource = Tablea;

Comment: @jdweng continues with the same error, only instead of 'Rows' happens 'DataSource' looks at the error:
Error CS1061 "DataGrid" does not contain a definition for "DataSource" and could not find any "DataSource" extension method that accepts a first argument of type "DataGrid" (is there a usage directive or missing assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using a DataGridView or something else?  If it is a different control then you may have to use the binding property.

Comment: @jdweng I am using a DataGrid which is the same thing as a DataGridView is not it? I did not find the one with the name 'View' added.

Comment: Absolutely NO!!!

Comment: @jdweng could you tell me how I get access to a DataGridView?

Comment: DGV is only available on a Form.  You have a wpf.  So bind like solutions on following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf

Comment: @jdweng I managed to solve my problem, I had created the project in WPF so I did not find the DataGridView now I created another project in Windows Form and implemented that code! Thank you for your help and patience.