# How to bind DataGrid rows to items in list of classes?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with a list property. The list contains objects with properties. How can I bind a DataGrid where each row is an object from the list and each column is a property of the object? Let me know if I can clear any confusion, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have any code sample? You should be able to specify the list as the item source - ItemsSource="{Binding Source=YourListName}" Take a look at this fro more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply I'll check out the article. I'm not really sure if code would help since there are so many different classes and functions interacting. When I use the ItemsSource="{Binding Source=YourListName}, what should my DataContext be? Should I use AutoGenerateColumns or make a column for each property of the the objects in the list? Thanks again.

Comment: I  think you will need to specify the datacontext property as the class name. And yes, i would say create each column yourself. The second answer in the link above shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below replace the binding objects with the objects that you want to populate with

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourListName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This shall populate all of your properties contained within the class in columns. By default AutoGenerateColumns property will be set to true

if you want to customize the column data that you want to display you can use something like below

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourListName, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyName1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header2" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyName2}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header3" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyName3}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header4" Binding="{Binding Path=PropertyName4}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get it to recognize the name of my list? @Maddy

Comment: You have to bind your views datacontext to the viewmodel which has YourListName variable defined