# must declare the scalar variable @pp

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to get the quantity with a SQL query but it is not working;

```
     string selectrow;
        int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int columnindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        selectrow = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
        string query = @"select quantite_pdt from produits where ref_pdt = @pp";
        try
        {
            using (var conn = loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD())
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pp", int.Parse(selectrow));
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, loaddatabaseconnexion.connexion_BDD());
                string nbstr = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I don't understand because my variable @pp is been declared.

Comment: You are setting `command` again in the inner `using` and not adding the parameter.

Comment: Look at the line where you instantiate command. You should pass conn as the second parameter, not a new instance of your connection. Why do you need a second command? You should use cmd.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Are you getting null?  Is column in database for ref_pdt a string or integer?

Comment: @jdweng the title is their error message. :D

Comment: I see.  The conn is dispose outside the using so connection is null.  But then the error message make absolutely no sense.  The error message should indicate the command is not valid.

Comment: You've already demonstrated that you know [how to use parameters correctly in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409342/update-datagrid-with-dataset-c-sharp) so why do you use the very problematic approach of addwithvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a single command object here instead of two. Your code should look like this. I would suggest not using AddWithValue. It can get datatypes incorrect sometimes. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pp", int.Parse(selectrow));
                string nbstr = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
```