# How to bind WPF-Datagrid Control in Editor

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am coming from programming with WinForms and now start to change into WPF. In WinForms I could easily bind a DataGrid before Runtime, to adjust the columns without coding everything.

The WPF-Datagrid has the property "ItemsSource", but I don't understand how to bind it in editor. I have already a DataSource which refers to a SQL-Database, but it will not be shown in the property window.

How to do this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz4KW.png)

Comment: You bind it through XAML, `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsThatAreInYourViewModel}"/>`, and why does your DataGrid has a name?! There is no need for those in WPF.

Comment: I think I am to stupid for this. That was so easy in WinForms. Just drag & drop the dataSource to the Form and it was done!

Comment: Don't say that!! You just need to learn how to do it in` WPF`, WinForms was free for all, with` WPF` you would use `MVVM` pattern to stop people from doing everything they want, like they did in WinForms. Which makes it more testable, clearer code, allows separation of concerns etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to expose your collection as a public property
2. make it visible in the xaml (namespace include)
3. set up your DataContext correctly
4. create the binding in XAML and set up the columns, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf)

If you want to see the changes in your collection online, you have to use ObservableCollection<>

Comment: Did you look at the screenshot? Should the dataSource not viewable in this ItemSource.DataSource ?

Comment: I had a look at it, but I have never used the GUI to configure the data source. Maybe if you configure it in XAML, it will be visible there.