# Databinding to WPF datagrid via EF6 and already running SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Warning that I'm relatively new to WPF, EF6 (code first) and MVVM, so I'm counting on this to be a rookie mistake. My views are linked via GalesoftMVVM, using a locator. The xaml file does indeed pick up on things defined in my viewmodel.cs file

I asked a question about this earlier yesterday and got recommended to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, however even with that implemented my datagrid still only shows the headers and no rows unfortunately.

So far this is what I have, any tips or help would be appreciated.

What I would like to do is use the existing database to fill up the collection, and display it on the grid

Viewmodel.cs

```
public class View1 : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Table1> _columnCollection = new ObservableCollection<Table1>();
    public ObservableCollection<Table1> ColumnCollection
    {
        get { return this._columnCollection; }
        set { _columnCollection = value; }
    }
}
```

View1.xaml

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" x:Name="Datagrid" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False"

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Datamodel class

```
public class Table1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _ID;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            ID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

EFContext class

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext()  : base("name=EFConnectionstring")
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet <Table1> SQLTestTable { get; set; }
}
```

There are 5 rows of test data in table 1. Headers do show up in the datagrid. (Even when auto-generated columns are turned off & the datatextcolumns are removed, so header lines are definitely within the collection, just not the rows)

Comment: I think binding doesn't work because your data context is still ViewModel, and not each element in the collection

Comment: @Barracuda How would I go about adding these to the collection?

Comment: Basic question, but it's not clear from your code: Are you actually adding any `Table1` objects to your `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @ChrisMack I dont think so? This is all the code I have for the observablecollection. What would be the best way to go about adding objects(rows)?

Comment: I don't use EF so I'm not too familiar with it, but you need to retrieve a collection of `Table1` objects from your `SQLTestTable` `DbSet` and add them to the collection (e.g., with a `foreach` loop), or perhaps initialise the collection with them, i.e. `new ObservableCollection<Table1>(someListOfTable1ObjectsThatYouGetFromYourDbSet);`.

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/querying-data.

Comment: @ChrisMack Will look into it. I think a foreach loop would be the most useful solution, but  have no idea how to implemant that. Either way thanks for the link

Comment: Try this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf , which sets the datacontext of the grid to the collection.