# How can I show content of this array of objects? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have objects as below:

```
public class FootballTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TeamDate> TeamDates { get; set; }
}

public class TeamDate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeam { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display array of FootballTeam in DataGrid in WPF?

[image: Now data grid look like this]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MVVM pattern you can do as follows. You can create a Model (FootballTeam) as you did in the question, process this model in ViewModel and display it on your Screen.

You can find more detailed information about ObservableCollection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0). You can get detailed answers from the question about binding data to DataGrid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809816/datagrid-binding-in-wpf).

**Model**

```
public class FootballTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public static readonly ObservableCollection<FootballTeam> footballTeams = new ObservableCollection<FootballTeam>();

    public ICollectionView footballTeamsCollectionView { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        footballTeamsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(footballTeams);

        AddTeam(1,"Juventus","Italy",DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void AddTeam(int Id, string Name, string Country, DateTime Time)
    {
        var item = new FootballTeam();
        item.Id = Id;
        item.Name = Name;
        item.Country = Country;
        item.Time = Time;
        footballTeams.Add(item);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding footballTeamsCollectionView , IsAsync=True}"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Height="480">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TeamDates" Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
```

If you don't want to use the MVVM pattern, you can do as follows as a second option.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = footballTeamsCollection();
    }

    private List<FootballTeam> footballTeamsCollection()
    {
        List<FootballTeam> footballTeams = new List<FootballTeam>();
        footballTeams.Add(new FootballTeam()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Juventus",
            Country = "Italy",
            Time = DateTime.Now
        }); 

        footballTeams.Add(new FootballTeam()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Tottenham",
            Country = "England",
            Time = DateTime.Now
        });

        return footballTeams;
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Height="480">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TeamDates" Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: But TeamDates (in FootballTeam) is an array of dates

Comment: Why do you feel the need to create a separate class for time? Isn't it just a time?